# Unable to Catch Exceptions in Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, symfony-3.4

I am using symfony 3.4. I am not able to catch the Exception. Please help me out.

```
try{
        $a= 5/0;
}catch (\Exception $e){
        print_r('Exception Caught...');
}
```

error messsage: The server returned a

> 500 Internal Server Error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Division by zero is a Fatal Error, not an exception that can be caught.  You could however use the `set_error_handler` function to create an error handler that throws an exception instead:

Place the following code anywhere before your error causing code:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr) {
    throw new \Exception('Fatal Error: '.$errstr);
});
```